# Ordering data - R and Rstudio

Tags: r

I am still learning to use Statistical softwares and I have a question about R. I downloaded R and RStudio.
I have a data table which has one column with 5571 codes, one code in each line. Each code has 7 digits and I need to delete the last digit of each code. I want to know if I can do this in an easy way using the software R and how, because it is almost impossible to delete each number manually.
Please, I would appreciate if someone could help me telling how to do it or if there is another software that I could use.

Comment: This question is off-topic on cross-validated, and done-to-death on stack overflow.  But as you seem to be starting out, you probably don't know what terms to search for.  If you have a string vector  `x`, and you want the first 6 digits, you can use the `substr` command.  `substr(x,start=1,stop=6)`.  Check `?substr`.  If the codes are curently numeric, you can convert them to a string using `x<-as.character(x)`, and then back via `as.character(x)` after you trim the last digit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a programming question not statistics, post in stack overflow. But you can look at

```
> x <- 101:110
> x
 [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
> floor(x/10)
 [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11
```

or

```
> as.numeric(sub(".$","",x))
  [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11
```

or based off @generic_user's comment (numbers all need to be same length)

```
> as.numeric(substr(x,start=1,stop=2))
 [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11
```

Comment: The last strategy does _not_ require that the number of digits ( which I take to be what you meant by "length") be the same in all instances.

Comment: If you only want to drop the last digit, and all your numbers were of varying number of digits, then using substr with the start and stop parameters would be a bit more difficult (the stop would be different for every number). So technically yes, you are right, but the other methods are much much easier.